# Power Bi: I want my line graph to display actual raw data instead of automatically aggregating it to average

Tags: python, powerbi, data-analysis

on the x axis i have the date(months) and on the y-axis i have the price. My raw data (price) is already aggregated to average price by month, however when I plot it on the line graph visual it further aggregates it to average of my price. Could anyone please help with this issue =

I've tried to go to the data modelling and press do not summarize  the columns but that doesn't help.